# Spring Controller not producing XML

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I have in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authors", produces = {"application/json","application/xml"})
public class AuthorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Author> findAll() {
        return authorRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

when Accept : application/json the respose is ok
when Accept : application/xml the respose is 406 Not Acceptable

Any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. I had also registered Hibernate4Module() , but incorrectly. After I have solved that, now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you annotated your controller with `@RestController` it should work.

1. You don't need to add dependency to `jackson-core` - it's added automatically with `spring-boot-starter-web`.
2. You don't need to specify version to `jackson-dataformat-xml` - let Spring Boot manage versions for you.

Find below minimal setup to get XML serialization with Jackson work:

Dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Controller & serialized class

```
@RestController
class PersonController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    Person get() {
        return new Person("John Doe", 44);
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Request for XML:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/            
<Person><name>John Doe</name><age>44</age></Person>
```

Request for JSON:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/
{"name":"John Doe","age":44}
```